# Why tcp data send are breaked when weak connection

Tags: java, c++

I have a problem: when my server sends data to a client with a weak connection, the data is lost and never arrive.

Server send code (java)

```
public Client(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    timeout = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        in = socket.getInputStream();
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

public void write(String event, Object... objs) {
    String params = "";
    for (final Object obj : objs) {
        params += "," + obj;
    }

    try {
        out.write((event + params + ";").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        out.flush();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Client receive code (C++):

```
while (true)
{
    char buf[1024];
    long bytesRead = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        timeout = 0;
        receive(string(buf, 0, bytesRead));
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "_the data is lost_", and so is the connection. Just reconnect and continue. The data you _have_ received will _not_ be missing any parts.

Comment: What is a "weak connection". And what exactly do you see when you run a packet capture. Either you see the missing data, which indicate a receiver problem, or you don't see it, which indicates a sender problem. You cannot figure out anything else until you figure out where the problem is.

Comment: @qzfqzfqzf you do understand that long messages are broken up in chunks, don't you? You should never rely on receiving complete messages in one `recv` or `read` operation.

Comment: Just when I make the connection in Edge I stay connected but he miss some packets.

Comment: Ted Lyngmo, paacket are not received

Comment: clearly problem is `if (bytesRead > 0) .. else break;`. `bytesRead` equal zero doesn't mean you have read all data it means they didn't arrived to your machine yet. How did you opened socket (what parameters did you provided)?

Comment: yes but the problem is that when bytesRead not > 0 I break and I got disconnected but not here. It's the server who give up the send

Answer (score 0):

I think that open streams in constructor not good approach.
And stream must been closed (use try with resources in write method):

```java
try(out =  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())) {
  out.write((event + params + ";").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  out.flush();
  } catch (final IOException e) {
        }
```